# Custom protocol handler (URI) in HTML

Tags: html, protocols, handler

I want to use a custom protocol handler in html to launch a program with parameters.

I have created a key called EchoMe in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT that contains URL Protocol = "" and a EchoMe/shell/open/command key with (Default) = "c:\testapp\echome.exe" "%1" "%2".

echome.exe can have the parameter --echo-me text to throw it back (eg 'C:\testapp\echome.exe --echo-me text' opens the program and echos 'test')

Now I can't figure out how to decently call it in HTML.

So far I have tried passing 2 arguments (like a href="EchoMe:--echo-me Test") but that seems to be as wrong as it looks.

I also tried only passing one argument and change the call itself (open/command key with (Default) = "C:\testapp\echome --echo-me " "%1" and change the html to href="EchoMe:test" but still 'test' is not showing up in my window.

I'm very certain the problem is in the HTML but I couldn't find any useful information concerning that matter

Comment: Have you seen "Registering an application to a URI protocol" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)?  That seems pretty descriptive.  Also, for best results, consider registering in lower case.  Mixed case is hard to remember and tends to be confusing over time.  (That's my experience; yours may vary).

Comment: I used that kb to create the initial registry keys. The call itself  is not really the problem (clicking the link runs the program) but passing the arguments to it simply doesn't seem to work. Sadly the kb has no example for a decent html href call to pass the argument "--echo-me <text>" to the program which is what I am looking for. Of course using only lower case is a good idea, I'll change that in my registrys

Comment: I created a batch file that only echos %1 and apparently there is my problem: When I use href="EchoMe://<text>" the batch receives "EchoMe://<text>" instead of only the <text> that I want it to receive. Is there a possibility to only hand over the <text> without the EchoMe:// stuff in front of it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use URL encoding here. So this

```
C:\testapp\echome --echo-me
```

will become this:

```
C%3A%5Ctestapp%5Cechome%20--echo-me
```

In JS you can use encodeURIComponent(str) and encodeURI(str) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint,  though I'm afraid I'm not quite sure where to put it? I assumed the HTML only gets something like "echome://text" and the registry will call the program and hand over the text. Using the url encoding in the registry doesn't seem to work either.